# matplotlib における ax とは何を表す？

Tags: matplotlib

jupyter での plot 実行方法を調べていていると、しばしば、 ax をどうのこうのというような記述を見かけます。

ここでいう ax とは何でしょう？ 勝手に、 axis （軸）を表す省略系なのかな、と思いましたが、仮にそうだったとしても、どうもそれ以上の何かを表しているようだ、と思っています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

例えば[公式チュートリアル](https://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html)や[`Axes`クラスリファレンス](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#the-axes-class)には下記説明がありますし、想像される通り「`Axes`クラスのインスタンス」以上の深い意味はないと思われます。

> In this example, **`ax` is the `Axes` instance** created by the `fig.add_subplot` call above (remember `Subplot` is just a subclass of `Axes`) and when you call `ax.plot`, [...]

.

> [...] The events you can connect to are 'xlim_changed' and 'ylim_changed' and the callback will be called with func(*ax*) where ***ax* is the `Axes` instance**.